# 500 Server Error when trying to deploy locally on Xampp or Wamp for a repo on GitHub

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, localhost, wampserver

Hi All I have been trying to deploy the following webapp I found on github.(https://github.com/lpkapil/storemanager.git)

it is written in php using Laravel framework. I followed all the instructions on the readMe however it gives me the following error:

[image]

Im not sure what to do from here, I would like to use this to create a personal project that is of interest to me.

here is my virtual host information:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName storemanager2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/storemanager/public/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: check into storage/logs/laravel.log for more details.

Comment: provide us your project folder structure and your virtual host configuration

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If you use a public hostname like `storemanager.com`, how is this problem related to [tag:xampp], [tag:wampserver], **and** [tag:localhost]?

Comment: @PrateikDarji where would i find that file? on C:?

Comment: Hi guys I have made an update to the post with the questions asked

Comment: So you should call it bu storemanager2.com, or try localhost/storemanager/public. If the second option ia working well so the problem should be on your server config

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried to use a different version of PHP, i have tried to install Laravel then copy the contents of the repository into that project folder. I have installed composer as it was not installed im not sure what to do next

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto where would i be able to find my server config so i can post it here too, 

when you say "So you should call it bu storemanager2.com" is that in the virtual host?

Comment: @1amCharlie lets connect, I am author of this project, will help you to get it setup and debug the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a .htacces file setup? because I see you are running in a production environment.

If you are running in a production environment you'll need a .htaccess.

Try this;

1. Open phpmyadmin and create a database for your project.
2. Create a .env file and copy the contents from .env.example and paste into it.
3. In your .env file replace the following fields with your database credentials

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yourdatabasename
DB_USERNAME=yourmysqlusername
DB_PASSWORD=yourmysqlpassword
```

4. In command line cd to your project directory and follow all installation instructions in repo.
5. in command line type PHP artisan serve.

if you are in a production environment as above create a .htaccess file and copy the code below to it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization MemberHeader
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Should work fine now.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Which of these configuration steps helps to resolve the error 500?

Comment: In Laravel the 500 server error could occur due to permission issues, Environment variables not found or .env file not found on your root directory, PHP extensions problem, or Database problem. In this case, his folder structure was not shared that's why I gave a general answer to the problem.

Comment: @Nico Haase Xampp and some other popular local servers support virtual hosting

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual hosting"? How does this refer to the original problem? Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: @LatehLarry when i tried to install composer i get an error "Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ^7.2.5 but your php version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement." so i tried it using the following command "composer install --ignore-platform-reqs" it gives me this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\storemanager\vendor\symfony\polyfill-php80\bootstrap.php on line 23"

Comment: Well, that's why you should **never** use `ignore-platform-reqs` unless you really know what you are doing ;)

Comment: @NicoHaase haha evidently i dont lol

Comment: @LatehLarry this worked thanks i used Xampp and its running on local host now thanks a million